# Java: How to safe lock/unlock critical part, that is split between 2 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

When I have a critical part in one thread, i can use ReentrantLock to protect my critical block.

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
try {
    lock.lock();
    // do critical stuff
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Now I have a critical part that is split in two blocks and these blocks are executed in different threads, and third thread should wait until both parts are done.

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
// lock
// critical part 1
executor.execute(() -> {
    // critical part 2
    // unlock
});
```

Here I should switch from `ReentrantLock` to `Semaphore` (or something else?). But I cann't figure out, how to organize something like try/finally block in 2 different threads. Or, in other words, how to be sure that my lock will be released. Any suggestions?

Comment: A semaphore is for a limited resource, So I would advice against it. There are multiple ways to tackle the issue, depending on the exact problem, which brings me to the actual point: this feels like an [XY problem (`meta.stackexchange.com`)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What is done in those blocks? Why are the run on two threads?

Comment: In particular, @Sergiy, your first snippet doesn't do anything, except interact with other threads _also_ running into that _specific_ lock. It also sounds like both snippets are only run once ever (at least, for that lock instance) - but if not, i.e. they both are in loops and can run any number of times, what do you do if either partA or partB is always running, therefore, 'wait for both to be done' isn't a thing?

Comment: You don't want "critical part 2" to start until "critical part 1" is finished. You don't want "third thread" to do its thing until "critical part 2" is finished. In other words, you want to do three things _in sequence._ Why are you not doing all three things in the same thread? What is the benefit (if any) of having the three threads?

Comment: OK. It's a legacy code without proper separation between data manipulation and UI layer, where I must implement a new feature. We try to refactor this code, but it's a background job, that could take some monthes. And we cann't make a feature freeze for this time :(